# read a keyboard key inside while read

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have an script that search for some files, some of them with whitespaces, and due to that I'm using `while read`.
Inside of such loop I need to use read -p "Pause" for waiting for a key on each interaction. However rather than waiting for a key it is reading the first letter of the pipeline.
I need something like this:

```
find . -name "*.o3g" | grep "pattern" | while read line
do
    process "$line"
    read -p "Press any key to continue"
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're already using `bash`-specific code, either do (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible):

```
find . -name '*.o3g' -print0 | grep -z pattern |
  while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    process "$file"
    read -n1 -p 'Press any key to continue' < /dev/tty
  done
```

(where the character (note however that some keys send more than one character) is read from the controlling terminal).

Or, better since that also avoids `process`'s stdin from being the pipe from `grep`:

```
while IFS= read -u 3 -rd '' file; do
  process "$file"
  read -n1 -p 'Press any key to continue'
done 3< <(find . -name '*.o3g' -print0 | grep -z pattern)
```

(where the character is read from the unmodified stdin).

See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) for other potential problems with the way you process `find` output.

Here, maybe you can simply do:

```
find . -name '*.o3g' -path '*pattern*' -ok process {} \;
```

See also, to avoid any GNUism except `bash` itself:

```
find . -name '*.o3g' -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    [[ $file =~ pattern ]] || continue
    process "$file"
    read -n1 -p "Press any key to continue"
  done' bash {} +
```

Comment: That's right, forcing it from the tty worked (`< /dev/tty`).